# Oracle 21c Enterprise Edition with Oracle Developer 6i

Tags: database, oracle, forms, oracle21c

as long as i cannot find a way to communicate via Oracle Communities, i would like to ask if there is a special way to connect oracle developer 6i (fmx) with oracle database 21c enterprise edition.
Thnx

Comment: It doesn't appear that there is any secure, supported way to do what you're asking. The only recommendation I've seen - from Oracle - is to upgrade your 20+ year old version of Forms to something current. You can't expect something like that to work forever, especially in today's networked environment where new threats require constant upgrades and patching.

Comment: Just recently I've read that Forms 6i was never certified nor supported on any Oracle database version after 8x, so anyone - who made it work - had to *tweak* this and that, and yet not being sure that it'll actually work properly. If it doesn't, you're on your own as Oracle didn't/doesn't guarantee that it will work, nor will they provide any support. As @pmdba said: upgrade.